# Finding the number of lines in a UITextView iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I've been researching this for hours and have not found a solid answer for this in ios 7. 
I have a requirement that I need to find out how many lines of text are being displayed in the UITextView.
I'd like to know how many lines the string is taking up in the UITextView

Here is the string i want to use

```
self.txtView.text = @"Evolving from older bat-and-ball games, an early form of baseball         was being played in England by the mid-18th century. ";
```

I tried this

```
int numLines = self.txtView.contentSize.height/self.txtView.font.leading;
```

As well as many other things but it just says the same (incorrect) number every time, even when I change the string.

Comment: The value of `numLines` has nothing at all to do with the actual text in the text view. It's the number of lines that it can show given the height and font size. What value do you really want?

Comment: I need the number of lines that the textView is actually showing. by default there is some kind of auto-new-line thing that apple has. I'd like to know how that determines when to make a new line

Comment: You are still not being clear. Do you want to know how many lines total the given text will take in the text view or do you want to know how many lines of the given text are actually visible at the moment in the text view? Examples: Really long text might take 20 lines even though the text view can only show 5 lines (regardless of the actual text). Or short text might only need 3 lines at the moment even if the text view could show 5 lines. Do you want the 3, 5, or 20 in these examples?

Comment: i dont need to know how much the text could show. I just want to know how many lines are actually showing up on the text view so I can determine when to create a new text view (part of my app). thanks =)

Comment: I dont really get those examples..

Answer (score 0):

*[EDIT] Answer edited to provide a better solution / code (directly inspired from the Apple doc)*

---

You may use the `NSLayoutManager` of the `UITextView` to help you compute stuff like that

```
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
unsigned nbLines, glyphIndex
unsigned numberOfGlyphs = [layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
NSRange lineRange;

for (nbLines = 0, glyphIndex = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; ++nbLines)
{
    [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:glyphIndex effectiveRange:&lineRange];
    glyphIndex = NSMaxRange(lineRange); // Skip to after last glyph of the line for next iteration
}
NSLog(@"Number of lines: %u", nbLines)
```

Source & Detailed explanations: [Apple's Text Layout Programming Guide: "Counting lines of text"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

Comment: it fails if last character is '\n'